# How to disable the default cursor in UWP and use Gamepad Navigation?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to develop a UWP app using Visual Studio 2022 through WebView but when I run/launch the application on XBOX I'm getting a default cursor from the XBOX.

I've tried some of the methods that has been provided in the documentation to remove the cursor none of it worked. Below are the different codes that I've tried to fix this issue.

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App2"
RequiresPointer="Never"  --> (tried this method as well)
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <WebView 
            Source="https://luser.github.io/gamepadtest/">
        </WebView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
public App() {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.RequiresPointerMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.ApplicationRequiresPointerMode.WhenRequested;
        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
}
```

I've tried with these methods by going through all the documentation and forums but still not able to get rid of the cursor. I need to remove the cursor throughout the application and wanted to use Gamepad for the navigation.

So, please provide me some inputs on how I can resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable the default cursor in WebView, and you can't do it in webview2 either, because these controls need mouse-like interactions inside.

In the document [Gamepad and remote control interactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/input/gamepad-and-remote-interactions#mouse-mode), you can see the following instructions.

> As described in XY focus navigation and interaction, on Xbox One the
> focus is moved by using an XY navigation system, allowing the user to
> shift the focus from control to control by moving up, down, left, and
> right. However, some controls, **such as WebView and MapControl, require
> a mouse-like interaction where users can freely move the pointer
> inside the boundaries of the control.**

Comment: was it like we can't disable it at all or we can switch between the pointer and the gamepad navigation?

Comment: You can't switch between pointer and gamepad navigation in WebView.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm correct but in the documentation it has been mentioned like we can disable the pointer mode in XBOX by adding the gamepadInputEmulation = 'keyboard'. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/how-to-disable-mouse-mode

when i use this I'm able to disable but need to click on the XBOX button on the controller and then close the menu bar which will make the cursor disappear.

Comment: Maybe you can test that code using InvokeScriptAsync, var value = await webview.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[]{ "navigator.gamepadInputEmulation = \"gamepad\"" });